# html/css columns all change size but I only want one to

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I was wandering if there was a way to make my little code idea look better by only changing the size of the hovered column so that the second one does not have some empty space at the bottom when hovering the first one?

Any ideas / solutions? thanks

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.appear_on_hover {
  display: none;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.Column:hover .appear_on_hover {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.Column {
  background: #ddd; 
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.Column:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">
    <h4>
      <br>
      <b>col 1</b>
      <br> some text
      <div class="appear_on_hover">
        test l1 <br> test l2 <br> test l3
      </div>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <h4>
      <br>
      <b>col 2</b>
      <br> some text
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

don't take attention to the text, just some french stuff, I have this:
[image: img1]

and would like something like this:
[image: img2]

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what the issue is? I can't quite tell with the code provided

Comment: But, your code does that already. Added a background to `.Column` to make it more obvious. Could you elaborate your question? Your question does not align with the code and images your provided.

Comment: I inverted the images cuz I'm dumb, so no it does not anymore

Comment: Well don't use table display to start with if you don't want it to look like a tabl6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set your `.Column-appear` as `position: absolute;` and play in hover with it's `transform: translateY()` and `opacity` and `visibility` instead of `display`
- Don't use `<div>` inside `<h4>`, instead use a separate DIV to distinguish `.Column-content` and `.column-appear`

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.Row {
  display: flex;               /* change this */
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /* table-layout: fixed;      /* Remove this */
  /* border-spacing: 10px;     /* Remove this */
}

.Column {
  position: relative;          /* add this */
  flex: 1;                     /* add this */
  transition: .5s;
  margin: 0 10px; /* add this for some spacing */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 2px #4444dd);
}

.Column-content,               /* New DIV in HTML! */
.Column-appear{                /* new! */
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.Column-appear {                /* Use a better className */
  /* display: none;             /* remove this */
  visibility: hidden;           /* add this */
  opacity: 0;                   /* add this */
  position: absolute;           /* add this */
  width: 100%;                  /* add this */
  border-top: none;             /* add this */
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px; /* add this */
  transform: translateY(-30%) ; /* add this */
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.Column:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 1;                   /* add this */
  /* transition: .5s;           /* Remove this */
}

.Column:hover .Column-appear {
  visibility: visible;          /* add this */
  opacity: 1;                   /* add this */
  transform: translateY(-20px); /* add this */
  /* transition: .5s;           /* Remove this */
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">
    <div class="Column-content">
      <h4>col 1<br>some text 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="Column-appear">
      test l1<br> test l2<br> test l3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <div class="Column-content">
      <h4>col 2<br>some text</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="Column-appear">
      test l2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">
    <div class="Column-content">
      <h4>col 1<br>some text 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Column">
    <div class="Column-content">
      <h4>col 2<br>some text</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="Column-appear">
      test l1<br> test l2<br> test l3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for all the details, and good usage. I appreciate it

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using `display: flex` instead of a table if possible. There are various flex-properties such as `justify-content`, `align-items`, and `flex-grow` that can help ensure items in a grid-like layout are the same size in each row. They are currently different heights because of the different amount of text content and text lines.

Comment: I inverted the images so actually the problem is different, oops